# Are shortend URLs generated from git.io persistent?

Tags: github

I'd like to use [git.io](http://git.io) shortened URLs in my publicly available document. Will the links ever get recycled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They won't get recycled. If Git.io ever shuts down, of course, they won't work anymore, but that's not likely to happen soon.